# Good approach in designing game classes

Tags: java, oop

I took a semester-long course in java but I'm still a beginner in Object-Oriented programming paradigm. Suppose that I want to create a simple game where the player can go to different locations. Each location has its own unique treasure (that has other attributes) and has its own set of different animals. The question: How can I design classes that are not too naive based on the game? (can be too broad) Is my approach below correct or can it be improved? (narrowed)

I was thinking that I should create a Location, treasure, and Animal classes; Each classes declared in its own file.

```
public class Location {
    // attributes such as treasure and animals
    private ArrayList<Animal> animals;
    private Treasure treasure;
    public Location(String name) {
        // initialization of attributes
        if(name.equals("Jungle")) {
            treasure = new Treasure("Rare Vine");
            animals.add(new Animal("Monkey", 90, 50);
            animals.add(new Animal("Snake", 100, 60);
        }
        else if(name.equals("Valley")){
            // and so on
        }
        // and so forth
    }
}
public class Treasure {
    // attributes such as name and value
    public Treasure(String name, int value) {
        // initialization of attributes
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
public class Animal {
    // attributes such as name
    public Animal(String name, int encounterRate, int captureRate) {
        // initialization of attributes
        this.name = name;
        this.encounterRate = encounterRate;
        this.captureRate = captureRate;
    }
}
```

But I doubt that the use of conditional statements in Location class to initialize its attributes makes the method have so many lines and may confuse the developer after some time. what if there are so many attributes per location and there are many locations?

Another approach that I can think of is to create subclasses of Location and put the corresponding values for the location's attributes. For me, I can understand the structure of the game and efficient if the number of location subclasses is small.

I'm new in creating java games so I don't have a solid view in designing game classes. this problem may be broad so I narrowed it down to my code above.

Comment: This question does not really belong to this site. Because it's not really a game programming related question. I'll give you an advice, don't be too concerned about patterns or writing "clean code" right away. It's way harder to actually finish a game than write perfect code. Just use what ever method size you can and later chop it in pieces. PS: i flagged this as off topic.

Comment: I respectfully disagree with @Katu. I think now is the perfect time to start thinking about design patterns and writing clean code.

Comment: Ideally you would store this kind of data in one or multiple external files using something like json or xml. But For simple testing this will work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about reviewing your code. It might work well on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I design classes that are not too naive based on the game?

The trick is to:

1. Make a rough design (as you've done).
2. Implement it (as you're doing).
3. Test it.
4. Adjust 1 and 2 as required, carry out 3, then rinse and repeat until it feels right.

If you feel it can be improved, improve it until you do not feel the need to improve it any more.

Don't get too caught up in the design phase though, it's very important to implement and test. This is a very subjective topic, as it's your game, your vision, your design at the end of the day, but iterating until it feels complete is the way to go.

Ideas and designs are easy - actually making them happen is another. If need be, your code and structure acts as the game's design. It's a living, changing document. Start with an idea and evolve it as you test and progress.

What you have sounds like a good start, so test it out, adjust as required. I would not worry about what you're worrying about, as even the act of posting your question here has you stopped in your tracks -- you've imposed a problem on yourself before it's actually been deemed a problem. Don't second-guess for now, just say, "this works well enough for now, I'll keep going". If it becomes an issue when it is actually an issue, change it then; it's okay to refactor when the need arises. For now, go forth with what you've got, don't get caught out with the entire design before the game's actually been made.

There are so many different ways to accomplish different things with programming, but failure to actually make them happen can happen if you dwell too much. If things start to get confusing, write documentation to help clear up any confusion. Some systems are very complex, it happens. Start small, iterate, advance, and repeat until you call your game done. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. My way of thinking about classes has improved. And my mind became clear for what I should do :)

Comment: Excellent, good to hear. Keep going! Design theory is good but coding is better. Comes a bit with experience and actually implementing things and trying it out, gaining knowledge through that. But yeah, since it's very subjective, up to you to make it work for your needs. If it's working, must be doing something right :)